# mongoose findOne, How do i find an element from an array of object?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to find and check if that user has a value on a certain item.

**Sample model data**:

```
user: {
    _id: 1,
    profilePictures: [
        {
            id: 1,
            image: 'sample.png'
        },

        {
            id: 2,
            image: null
        },

        {
            id: 3,
            image: null
        }
    ]
}
```

**My Mongoose.find query**:

```
const user = await userModel.findOne({
                                    _id: 1,

                                    profilePictures: {
                                        $elemMatch: {
                                            $and: [
                                                { id: 2, image: null },
                                                { id: 3, image: null }
                                            ]
                                        } 
                                    }
                                })
```

but its returning nothing, I know i could just get the user and use Array.some() on profilePictures or some other Array function to check if an array item with position 2 and 3 has also a property image with a value of null

but since I'm learning Mongoose i am trying to find a way to do it that way.

Comment: What is your expected output from the sample in the question. I ask, since in your a filter on `position` field is there but it is absent in the sample data.

Comment: oh sorry replace position with id

Comment: thanks but, this isn't the query im looking for

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to find the document for particular indexes, and the array is just one level, you could use this simple query

```
db.getCollection('somecollection').find({ "_id": 1, "profilePictures.1.image": null, "profilePictures.2.image": null })
```

Comment: Would there be other way without the index?

just check the array of object if the item object with id: 2 also contains property image containing null, and the object with id: 3 also contains property image containing null

Comment: tried this one, i thought it would work not sure why it wont, if the "profilePictures.0.image" is not null i should only receive null from the query, but i still received something

Answer (score 0):

So for now, I figured out a solution that doesn't use a complicated mongoose query.
I just validated it using JavaScript.

```
// req.body.id is an array of number

const user: any = await db.getCollection('somecollection').findOne({ _id: 1 })

let isAllPositionAvailable = true

for (const position of req.body.id) {
    isAllPositionAvailable = user.profilePictures.find((x: any) => x.id === parseInt(position)).image === null

    if (!isAllPositionAvailable) break
}

if (!isAllPositionAvailable) {
     return res.status(400).send({
          message: 'Image position is not available, please remove the existing image first'
     })
}
```